# Proving that $u(x)=\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(y) \frac{e^{-i k |x -y|}}{|x-y|} d^3 y$ obeys $L u(x) = -f(x)$ for $L=\Delta + k^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I am self studying PDEs and have come across the following problem regarding distributions.

**Problem Statement:** Prove that
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(y) \frac{e^{-i k |x -y|}}{|x-y|} d^3 y$$
obeys
$$L u(x) = -f(x)$$
for
$$L=\Delta + k^2$$.

**Attempt:** I recall to mind the definition of the spherically symmetric Laplacian in polar coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$\Delta = \partial_r^2 + \frac{2}{r} \partial_r$$

Then, $f(y)$ is truly a coefficient function, so what is of principal significance remains in exhibiting

$$(\Delta + k^2) \frac{e^{-ikr}}{r} = -4 \pi \delta(r)$$

in the distributional sense.

$$
\begin{align}
(\Delta + k^2) \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{e^{-ikr}}{r} d^3 y &= 4 \pi \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} (\Delta + k^2) r e^{-ikr} dr \\
&= 4 \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\partial_r^2 + \frac{2}{r} \partial_r + k^2 \right) r e^{-ikr} dr \\
&= 4 \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(-2ik - k^2 r + \frac{2}{r} - 2ik + k^2 r \right) e^{-ikr} dr \\
&= 4 \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{r} - 4ik \right) e^{-ikr} dr
\end{align}
$$

**Where I'm Stuck:** I am not sure how to proceed as my final integrand appears ill-conditioned? Did I make an algebraic mistake?

**Other Thoughts:** I was curious as to if I might use the following identity in my answer.

For any $k \in \mathbb{R}$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} dx = 2 \pi \delta(x)
$$

Regarding the $\frac{2}{r}$ term, could I employ the Cauchy principle value of the integral or another such means of ascribing a value to it? If memory serves, the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{r}$ is not defined, so I believe that I must have taken a wrong path.

Ultimately, am I correct in my hope that proving

$$
(\Delta + k^2) \frac{e^{-ikr}}{r} = - 4 \pi \delta(r)
$$

will allow me to show

$$
\begin{align}
(\Delta + k^2) c_0 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(y) \frac{e^{-ikr}}{r} dy &= -4 \pi c_0 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(y) \delta(x -y) d^3 y \\
&= -4 \pi c_0 f(x)
\end{align}
$$

Then, $c_0= \frac{1}{4 \pi}$ would prove the desired result.

Comment: Fundamental solution/Greens functions proofs always require integration by parts in a formal distribution theory proof, and I don't see that anywhere here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I recall correctly, $\Delta$ can be viewed as $-4 \pi^2 |k|^2$ by repeatedly integrating by parts. I tried working that into my attempt at one point, but I wasn't certain how to proceed. Would this be closer to the right track?

Comment: Not quite, that's actually from considering the Fourier transform. Do you know how to do multivariate integration by parts?

Comment: I guess my comment was a bit vague. I would have to apply integration by parts repeatedly (twice to be exact) due to the presence of the second derivative. In one spatial dimension, the Laplacian would amount to a single second derivative meaning the result would be $-4 \pi^2 k^2$. In higher dimensions, we would have to do this for each coordinate axis meaning that the result would be $-4 \pi^2 (k_1^2 + k_2^2 + \dots + k_n^2) = - 4 \pi^2 |k|^2$.

Comment: I mean this expression: $$\int_\Omega u \nabla\cdot F\:dV = \oint_{\partial \Omega} u F \cdot dS - \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot F \:dV$$ where $u$ is a scalar field and $F$ is a vector field.